# Problem adding in a ASP.NET grid view image from SQL database

Tags: c#

I created a grid view that contains a column for images, after I write all necessary code the image is still not showing. Can you look at the code and see if there is something that i'm doing wrong? This is my ASP.NET Grid View:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="229px" Width="404px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <img id="img1" src='Handler1.ashx.cs?ProductID=<%# Eval("ProductID").ToString() %>' height="70" width="70"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkView" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' OnClick="lnk_OnClick">View</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is my button that when clicked should display the images in the ASP.NET grid view

```
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (sqlCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            sqlCon.Open();
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ProductCreateOrUpdate", sqlCon);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductID", (hfProductID.Value == "" ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(hfProductID.Value)));
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image", FileUpload2.FileBytes);
        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text.Trim());
        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        sqlCon.Close();
        string productID = hfProductID.Value;
        Clear();
        if (productID == "")
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Saved Successfully";
        else
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Updated Successfully";
        FillGridView();
    }
```

And this is the general Handler.ashx

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string Constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[@"connection String"].ToString();
        string pici = context.Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
        using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(Constr))
        {
            using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("SELECT Image FROM Product WHERE ProductID=@ProductID", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter("ProductID", pici));
                conn.Open();
                using (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
                {
                    reader.Read();
                    context.Response.BinaryWrite((Byte[])reader[reader.GetOrdinal("Image")]);
                    reader.Close();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is your handler firing? Does your reader have data? Inspecting with a debugger, what does it tell you?

Comment: How can i verify if my handler is firing? And the reader has data because there are already items in the database. The only thing that the debugger is telling me is this: Exception thrown: 'System.Threading.ThreadAbortException' in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Use your debugger to verify it is running, set a break point.

Comment: I verified now and its not firing. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Does your GridView show rows?